# error compiling idevicerestore in Mint

Tags: compilation, linux-mint

i have a problem compiling idevicerestore in Mint ..
i did installed and compiled all required packages ..

> libusbmuxd, libfuse, ifuse, libimobiledevice, libirecovery and
>   libplist

here is my problem ..

> ```
> makemake  
> all-recursive
> make[1]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/Downloads/idevicerestore-master'
> Making all in src
> make[2]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/Downloads/idevicerestore-master/src'
>
>   CC       idevicerestore-dfu.o
> dfu.c: In function ‘dfu_get_cpid’:
> dfu.c:243:48: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>   const struct irecv_device_info *device_info = irecv_get_device_info(client->dfu->client);
>                                                 ^
> dfu.c:248:21: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>   *cpid = device_info->cpid;
>                      ^
> dfu.c: In function ‘dfu_get_ecid’:
> dfu.c:260:48: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>   const struct irecv_device_info *device_info = irecv_get_device_info(client->dfu->client);
>                                                 ^
> dfu.c:265:21: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>   *ecid = device_info->ecid;
>                      ^
> dfu.c: In function ‘dfu_is_image4_supported’:
> dfu.c:278:48: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>   const struct irecv_device_info *device_info = irecv_get_device_info(client->dfu->client);
>                                                 ^
> dfu.c:283:21: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>   return (device_info->ibfl & IBOOT_FLAG_IMAGE4_AWARE);
>                      ^
> dfu.c: In function ‘dfu_get_ap_nonce’:
> dfu.c:293:48: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>   const struct irecv_device_info *device_info = irecv_get_device_info(client->dfu->client);
> dfu.c:304:29: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>    memcpy(*nonce, device_info->ap_nonce, *nonce_size);
>                              ^
> dfu.c: In function ‘dfu_get_sep_nonce’:
> dfu.c:317:48: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>   const struct irecv_device_info *device_info = irecv_get_device_info(client->dfu->client);
> dfu.c:328:29: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>    memcpy(*nonce, device_info->sep_nonce, *nonce_size);
>                              ^
> make[2]: *** [idevicerestore-dfu.o] Error 1
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/Downloads/idevicerestore-master/src'
> make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/Downloads/idevicerestore-master'
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```